# Problem associating file types for iPad running IOS4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios

I'm trying to associate zip files with my program I'm writing for the iPad, but am running into problems. My custom file format that I created is recognized just fine in email attachments and dropbox. However, zip files are only recognized from dropbox and not from email attachments, (EG. dropbox->open in->my program). In email attachments it won't let me download the file and select 'open in'. This is really strange since it works fine in dropbox. The weirdest thing is that if I install Goodreader, the files work just fine as email attachments. I'm developing this program for enterprise distribution, so I'd rather not make all the employees have to buy Goodreader in order to open zip files from email attachments. I've included two .plist configurations that I've tried. Both only work if goodreader is installed.

[image]

and:

[image]

If anyone has any suggestions, I'm really stumped on this one.

Comment: If you install Goodreader then your app shows up in Mail's Open In... menu for .zip files?? But if you uninstall Goodreader then your app does not show up in Mail's Open In... menu? Just trying to be sure that I understand. Thx.

Comment: I uninstalled the programs and it still worked, but on someones iPad that doesn't have goodreader, it doesn't work. If they install goodreader, it will work, even if they uninstall goodreader. Weird. Any ideas why this won't work off the bat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out what was going on. In my info.plist file, I wasn't changing the bundle identifier to reflect my company name. Effectively it was registering my file types as com.novatek.iPadViewer, but it should have been com.yourcompany.iPadViewer. I changed the identifier to be com.novatek.iPadViewer and now it works great.